# How to remove double borders on stacked list items with no whitespace

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a list that usually contains around 30 images, I have `border: 1px solid #222;` on the images themselves. The problem I am running into is whenever my list goes on multiple rows the borders will stack on top of each other making certain borders look bigger than others.

Is there anyway to show a true `1px` border around all of my images regardless of which rows they are on?

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/NvobON?editors=0100) displaying my problem as well as the code below

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-inline search-filter__brand"><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1GAvUKVXXXXa0XpXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Nike/耐克"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1bKIvJVXXXXaJXVXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Adidas/阿迪达斯"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1z3wlKVXXXXXvXpXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Lining/李宁"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1IvS5KVXXXXaaXVXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Asics/亚瑟士"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1EQfUHpXXXXXDXpXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="ANTA/安踏"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB178.CHpXXXXbTapXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="NEW BALANCE"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1QLG5QFXXXXaAaFXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Under Armour/安德玛"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1sGfkHFXXXXc4XVXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Mizuno/美津浓"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1xttsSpXXXXcKXVXXXXXXXXXX_100x100.jpg" alt="Puma/彪马"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1ekhSJpXXXXbzXVXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="XTEP/特步"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1tBlBMXXXXXXaXFXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Skechers/斯凯奇"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1gmTGQFXXXXccXFXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Reebok/锐步"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1CbHlSpXXXXaYaXXXXXXXXXXX_100x100.jpg" alt="361°"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1RwT3HpXXXXbaXVXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="乔丹"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1MpgaHpXXXXXBXXXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Peak/匹克"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1zS.5JFXXXXaFXpXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="erke/鸿星尔克"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1RKW3IXXXXXXYXpXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Fila/斐乐"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1GrllRpXXXXbdXVXXXXXXXXXX_100x100.jpg" alt="Saucony/圣康尼"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1zPMqKFXXXXbdaXXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Decathlon/迪卡侬"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1QDzSHpXXXXatXpXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Le coq sportif/公鸡"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB145DUSFXXXXX1XpXXXXXXXXXX_100x100.jpg" alt="Warrior/回力"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1PhHOKXXXXXccXFXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="PLAYBOY/花花公子"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1dAMgIXXXXXcjXXXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="Camel/骆驼"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1g1NQQVXXXXaAXpXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="DOUBLE STAR/双星"></a></li><li><a><img src="//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/TB1aZ2VHpXXXXcwXXXXSutbFXXX.jpg_100x100.jpg" alt="贵人鸟"></a></li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS**

```
.search-filter{
    &__brand{
        li{
            padding: 0;
            width:100px;
        }
        img{
            border: 1px solid #222;
            width: 100px;
        }
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.search-filter__brand li {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.search-filter__brand img {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  width: 100px;
}
```

**Edit**
added screenshot for referance

[image]

Comment: do you want to have 2 little 1px borders like you have horizontally ? use margin-bottom:3px; or do you want to have the two margin to be one ?

Comment: Kind of a hack, but why don't you add in the CSS:

`li{margin-top: 5px;}`

Comment: I need to have no space between all of my images so that they are touching  just need to remove the double border problem

Comment: So the `double-border-problem` only occurs on left and right of the image right?

Comment: @NooBskie is this what you are looking for https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjqxbK?editors=0100

Comment: @Amal Unfortunatly no, I need to have no whitespace between items

Comment: Just add 
`li{border-right: 1px solid black;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black}`

instead of `border: 1px ....`

Comment: that wont help, ther will still be spaces between the li's and border missing on the top and left of the blocks

Comment: Added screenshot for referance

Comment: @NooBskie added codepen version on my answer, ask if you want the hover part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are maybe searching for negative margins then

```
li{
    padding: 0;
    width:100px;
    margin-right:-5px;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}
```

the margin bottom:-1px places the bottom divs 1px upper, and the right margin is 4px because you have a space between every li + 1px for the margin

caution when doing that, as 4px is only the width of 1em with your specific font size, so better say `-1em -1px` instead of `-5px`

[codepen version here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjdWxW?editors=1100).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

use `flex`

Remove border for image and set border for `ul` and `li`

```
.search-filter{
    &__brand{
        li{
        padding: 0;
        height: 62px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        }
        img{
            width: 100px;
        }
    }
}
ul.list-inline.search-filter__brand {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjqxbK?editors=1100)

Comment: really ? width: calc(100%/8 - 13px); ? that's not responsive and pretty dirty, not a bad habit to my mind (no need to add it's not all-browser compatible)

Comment: yeah, that's some clever way, but you still need a overflow:hidden conatiner, there is still no border on the left of the ul (try `ul{padding-left:10px;padding-top:50px;}` to see it), and if you want to higlight one of the li with a red border, then ... you cant ...